# Wrap useQuery of tRPC in a custom hook with correct TypeScript types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, trpc.io

I'm using [tRPC](https://trpc.io/) in a project with already existing API calls and would like to wrap the [`useQuery`](https://trpc.io/docs/client/react/useQuery) function into a separate wrapper, but I'm struggling with getting the TypeScript types right.

#### What I want

Here is what the ideal outcome looks like. Instead of the following code:

```js
const query = trpc.myendpoint.useQuery({ foo: 'bar' });
```

... I would like to write this:

```js
const query = useCustomHook(trpc.myendpoint, { foo: 'bar' });
```

#### Non-Typescript Solution

The JavaScript part is easy to implement but I struggle in getting the TypeScript types right. I want the `useCustomHook` to return the correct data type. Here is my `any` hack which technically works but provides no type hints:

```js
function useCustomHook(obj: any, queryData: any) {
    // ... Here I have some code related to my old code, which is why I need the custom hook
    return obj.useQuery(queryData);
}
```

#### What I tried so far

I tried the code below already and also tried [inferring types](https://trpc.io/docs/client/vanilla/infer-types) but did not get it to work. These were some of my approaches in which I already did not know how to type `queryData` properly:

```js
// Approach using the trpc object
type TrpcProcedure1 = (typeof trpc)[keyof typeof trpc];
function useCustomHook<T extends TrpcProcedure>(obj: TrpcProcedure1, queryData: ???) {}
// Error when calling obj.useQuery:
// Property 'useQuery' does not exist on type 'TrpcProcedure'.

// Approach going via AppRouter['_def']['procedures']
type TrpcProcedure2 = (typeof trpc)[keyof AppRouter['_def']['procedures']];
function useCustomHook<T extends TrpcProcedure>(obj: TrpcProcedure2, queryData: ???) {}
// Error when calling obj.useQuery:
// This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type 'ProcedureUseQuery<...>' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other
```

Unfortunately, both resulted in error messages as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work (thanks to help from the tRPC discord):

```js
import { DecorateProcedure, UseTRPCQueryResult } from "@trpc/react-query/shared";
import { AnyQueryProcedure, inferProcedureInput, inferProcedureOutput } from "@trpc/server";
import { TRPCClientErrorLike } from "@trpc/client";

function useCustomHook<QueryProcedure extends AnyQueryProcedure, U, V extends string>(
    proc: DecorateProcedure<QueryProcedure, U, V>,
    params: inferProcedureInput<QueryProcedure>
): UseTRPCQueryResult<inferProcedureOutput<QueryProcedure>, TRPCClientErrorLike<QueryProcedure>> {
    // custom code...
    return proc.useQuery(params);
}
```

Using this code, the input as well as the output is properly typed.

`DecorateProcedure<QueryProcedure, U, V>` is the procedure type, where `QueryProcedure extends AnyQueryProcedure`. The input parameters can then be inferred via `inferProcedureInput<QueryProcedure>`. Similarly, the output type can be inferred via `inferProcedureOutput<QueryProcedure>` and then wrapped into `UseTRPCQueryResult`.